# Why my Redmine site is shown without any Virtual Host settinig?

Tags: virtualhost, redmine, centos7

I've installed Redmine 3.2.4.stable.16111 on to my VPS. I haven't written any Virtual Host settings for Redmine. Only added server name "redmine" as CNAME to my DNS records.

Why Redmine works without Virtual Host settings?

I installed Redmine according to Redmine's official Japanese page, so I guess it was installed at /var/lib/redmine/. But under that directory, no "public" folder. So I also wonder why Redmine works fine.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well Redmine is written in Ruby language. A Redmine website can be served by different web servers, such as Apache, Nginx. Web brick is a simple http server written in Ruby language that can be used to quickly get started with Redmine. By default it runs over port 3000. It does not require any virtual hosts.

Redmine can also be run with a combination of web servers. For example Apache web server can work as reverse proxy for the Web brick server.